# Multiple criteria on lhs for R Apriori

Tags: r, apriori

I'm trying to get the R apriori algorithm to allow me to specify multiple attributes I want on the lhs, at the same time.

```
rules <- apriori(Data, parameter=list(supp = 0.0001, conf = 0.001, minlen = 2), appearance = list(lhs = c("DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen"), default="rhs"))
```

The above line would filter the lhs for just a certain DiagnoseTekst (the columns in my data are 'MedicatieTekst', 'Geslacht' and 'DiagnoseTekst')
However, I would like it to filter on BOTH DiagnoseTekst AND Geslacht. When I put in

```
rules <- apriori(Data, parameter=list(supp = 0.0001, conf = 0.001, minlen = 2), appearance = list(lhs = c("DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen", "Geslacht=M"), default="rhs"))
```

I get some rules with just DiagnoseTekst, and some with just Geslacht. (while in this case, most cases should have both attributes). Is there any way to filter either the search or the results to be able to specify multiple criteria for the lhs column?

Full code to be clear:

```
Data <- as(data, "transactions")

str(Data)
rules <- apriori(Data, parameter=list(supp = 0.0001, conf = 0.001, minlen = 2), appearance = list(lhs = c("DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen"), default="rhs"))
top.conf <- sort(rules, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA, by = c("confidence","lift"))
set <- inspect(head(subset(top.conf), 30))
```

Example of output:

```
> set <- inspect(head(subset(top.conf), 30))
     lhs                                rhs                                                support     confidence  lift      count
[1]  {DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen} => {Geslacht=V}                                       0.066477566 0.525500378 1.1539592 30561
[2]  {DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen} => {Geslacht=M}                                       0.060025798 0.474499622 0.8712635 27595
[3]  {DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen} => {MedicatieTekst=FUROSEMIDE}                        0.017917467 0.141636289 2.9290550  8237
[4]  {DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen} => {MedicatieTekst=METOPROLOL}                        0.006279923 0.049642341 0.9877311  2887
[5]  {DiagnoseTekst=Acuut hartfalen} => {MedicatieTekst=PARACETAMOL}                       0.005201003 0.041113557 0.6085413  2391
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to make sure that two specified items have to occur in the LHS of the rule. Appearance only can restrict which items MAY occur in the rule, but not that all of them HAVE to be present. However, you can use filtering with `subset` to solve this problem. The following code finds all rules with the items "age=Senior" and "sex=Male" in the LHS of the rule using `%ain%` (all in; see `? "%ain%"`)

```
> library("arules")
> data(Adult)

> rules <- apriori(Adult)
> rules
set of 6137 rules 

> rules <- subset(rules, lhs %ain% c("age=Senior","sex=Male"))
> rules
set of 167 rules 

> inspect(head(rules, by = "lift", n  = 3))
    lhs                                    rhs                    support confidence lift count
[1] {age=Senior,                                                                               
     marital-status=Married-civ-spouse,                                                        
     sex=Male,                                                                                 
     capital-gain=None,                                                                        
     native-country=United-States}      => {relationship=Husband}    0.12          1  2.5  5687
[2] {age=Senior,                                                                               
     marital-status=Married-civ-spouse,                                                        
     race=White,                                                                               
     sex=Male,                                                                                 
     capital-gain=None,                                                                        
     native-country=United-States}      => {relationship=Husband}    0.11          1  2.5  5293
[3] {age=Senior,                                                                               
     marital-status=Married-civ-spouse,                                                        
     sex=Male,                                                                                 
     capital-gain=None,                                                                        
     capital-loss=None,                                                                        
     native-country=United-States}      => {relationship=Husband}    0.11          1  2.5  5238
```